# Acrobat Autofocus

Tags: javascript, pdf, acrobat, autofocus

Does anyone know a script for autofocusing on a field in a pdf? I tried the standard javascript .focus() method on page open, but it doesn't seem to like it. Given that I can't find anything on Google about it, I'm torn between "it can't be done" or "it's so simple I missed it." If anyone knows of anything, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Someone in the Adobe forum helped me out with this one.

```
    getField("fieldName").setFocus();
```